# test class - help me to get 100%

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage

**class**:

[image]

**test class:**

```
@isTest
private class newTaskTest{

    static testMethod void createTask() 
    {
        Lead lead = new Lead(LastName='febrian',company='febrian test');
        insert lead;
        Account acc = new Account(Name='test');
        insert acc;
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(AccountId=acc.Id,Name='test opp',StageName = 'Prospecting',CloseDate = date.today());
        insert opp;

        PageReference pR = Page.newTaskContactLayout;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pR);

        ApexPages.Standardcontroller sc = new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(lead);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',lead.id);

        newTaskController ntc = new newTaskController(sc);

        Task tsk = new Task(Status='Completed',Subject='Reached Call',Type='Reached Call',Description='test',ActivityDate=System.today(),whoId =lead.id);
        insert tsk;
        ntc.saveTask();

        ApexPages.Standardcontroller sc2 = new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(opp);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',opp.id);

        newTaskController ntc2 = new newTaskController(sc2);

        Task tsk2 = new Task(Status='Completed',Subject='Reached Call',Type='Reached Call',Description='test',ActivityDate=System.today(),whatId =lead.id);
        insert tsk2;
        ntc2.saveTask();

        system.assertEquals(null, pR);
    }  
    static testMethod void updateTimestamp(){
        //PageReference pr = Page.newTaskContactLayout;
        //Test.setCurrentPage(pr);
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'Test Account';
        insert acc;

        Contact cont = new Contact();
        cont.AccountId = acc.Id;
        cont.FirstName = 'FirstName';
        cont.LastName = 'LastName';
        cont.Email='flname@email.com';
        insert cont;

        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(AccountId = acc.Id,Name='test opp',StageName = 'Prospecting',CloseDate = date.today());
        insert opp;

        test.startTest();
        //Test.setCurrentPageReference(pr);
        test.setCurrentPage(Page.newTaskContactLayout);

        ApexPages.StandardController sc2 = new ApexPages.StandardController(opp);
        //ApexPages.StandardSetController sc2 = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(opp);
        //sc2.setSelected(opp);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',opp.id);

        newTaskController ntc2 = new newTaskController(sc2);
        cont.Follow_Up_Timestamp__c = System.NOW();
        update cont;
        ntc2.callQueue();

        ApexPages.StandardController sc3 = new ApexPages.StandardController(cont);
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',cont.id);

        newTaskController ntc3 = new newTaskController(sc3);
        cont.Follow_Up_Timestamp__c = System.now();
        update cont;
        ntc3.callQueue();
        //system.assertEquals(null, pR);  
    }
}
```

after run test, I got code coverage 80%. Could anybody give me solutions to resolve this? I need 100% coverage asap. Thank you.

Comment: if you look at the red line you are checking for object prefix. 006 points to opportunity.If you run this method with the lead id pointing to an opportunity id you will get coverage for those 2 lines.

Comment: Can I ask why do you want 100% coverage? It's a common misconception that 100% is a good thing to aim for. Personally, I think that the important thing is to test that your business logic is well covered. Tests should be reliable enough to ensure that what the business wants is achieved, yet flexible to allow you to change how you implement it. Aiming for 100% coverage will essentially fossilize your implementation and force you to change your tests every time you modify/refactor the implementation.

Comment: Does your first test fail? It should at this `system.assertEquals(null, pR);` as `pR` is not null that I can see. Second your tests are smoke screen test and are not actually testing anything. If you attack your testing from a process / business requirement perspective coverage will come organically. Test both positive and negative use cases. Each test method should focus on a single narrow requirement not the whole class

Answer (score 1):

Parameters are case sensitive.

Change (Uppercase **I**):

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',opp.id);
```

to (lowercase **i**)

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('id',opp.id);
```

To enter the else condition although it i odd the else line is not covered at all so you may been generating an error prior to that part of your code....

Comment: You can remove case sensitivity by actually making use of the `StandardController`, which has a `getId()` method.

Comment: When appropriate yes good point

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are not using two Contact instances and one Opportunity instance that are mentioned as `{get;set;}` in your code. You are creating the similar named instances in your `callQueue()` method. To cover the instances you can do the following inside your updateTimestamp() test method after initializing `ntc2`:

```
ntc2.con = cont;
ntc2.contact = cont;
ntc2.opp = opp;
```

In order to fulfill else if condition, you will need to change the following code inside your updateTimestamp() test method:

From

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',opp.id);
```

To

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',acc.id);
```

If you find any problem, please inform.

Comment: If you notice the else condition has and || on account and opp. If it does not enter for an Opp it won't enter for an acc